# How can I get the number of hardware level threads in my computer?

Tags: command-line, cpu

How can I get the number of hardware level threads in my computer using the ubuntu terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Using `lscpu`:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               806.347
BogoMIPS:              4988.30
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

The OS recognizes each hardware thread as a different CPU. The number you want is show at line `CPU(s):`, which is the same as multiplying `Thread(s) per core:`, `Core(s) per socket:` and `Socket(s):`.

Or you can use a single command:

```
lscpu -p | grep -c "^[0-9]"
```